# extract text file from user derived source

Tags: matlab, directory

I am building a code in matlab. I have 2 folders called EXP1, and EXP2, and within each of those folders are 4 subfolders, labelled 1-4. I have a code which adds each path to matlab, which may help visualize this:

```matlab
clear
%add complete paths to every template file you will be using
addpath('C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT1\1',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT1\2',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT1\3',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT1\4',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT2\1',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT2\2',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT2\3',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT2\4');
```

Each of the text files is named EXP(n)_SQ(m)_Template, with the EXP folder number replacing n, and the subfolder replacing m. 
I want a user to be able to input a specific number for an experiment, and squad, and have that file used for the remainder of the script.
Here is what I have:

```matlab
clear
%add complete paths to every template file you will be using
addpath('C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT1\1',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT1\2',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT1\3',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT1\4',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT2\1',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT2\2',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT2\3',...
    'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox (*******)\******* Team Folder\Matlab\RFID chip reader\EXPT2\4');
user_input_exp = input('Enter Experiment Number: ', 's');
user_input_squad = input('Enter Squad Number: ', 's');
Mac_Templ = importdata('EXP(user_input_exp)_SQ(user_input_squad)_Template.txt');
```

I get this error:

```matlab
Error using importdata (line 139)
Unable to open file.
Error in test_editing (line 17)
Mac_Templ = importdata('EXP(user_input_exp)_SQ(user_input_squad)_Template.txt');
```

If I take away the '' surrounding the file name, I get this error by the underscores:

```matlab
Error: File: test_editing.m Line: 17 Column: 43
Invalid text character. Check for unsupported symbol, invisible character, or pasting of
non-ASCII characters.
```

Any help is appreciated.

running MATLAB r2019b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`sprintf`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) or some other string formatting solution. The `input` function will return a string, which you can use to form the filename:

```
Mac_Templ = importdata(sprintf('EXP%s_SQ%s_Template.txt', user_input_exp, user_input_squad));
```

Another possibility is to concatenate the character vectors:

```
Mac_Templ = importdata(['EXP' user_input_exp '_SQ' user_input_squad '_Template.txt']);
```